# How to make gdb load debugging symbols if there are multiple code sections?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

I'm developing a loadable kernel module under Linux. My module is named `mydrv.ko`.

I want to manually load the symbols before `module_init`.

According to the [tutor](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/DebuggingLinuxKernel), I use the gdb command `add-symbol-file` as follows:

```
add-symbol-file mydrv.ko 0xcf030060 -s .data 0xcf030488 -s .bss 0xcf030519
```

That seems good. However, by examining `mydrv.ko`'s section information, I observes there are more than one code section, say:

```
.text._ZN6DriverD2Ev 0xa00fd13a
.text._ZN6DriverC2Ej 0xa00fd10e
```

How should I load the symbol information of these code sections? Just append `-s section-name section-address` to the command `add-symbol-file`?

Comment: The revision date on your tutorial is 2003. Try working through [a more up-to-date](http://www.elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb) one instead.